# Autofixture, class as the generated class object?

Tags: c#, autofixture

I've been researching and I'm starting to get the idea that this is possible but Autofixture has some rabbitholes.

Writing a fakes class, I have a `States` class in my legit class that I want to define as an Autofixture generated object on class instantiation in my fakes project class.

Something like the following:

```
namespace Geo.Fakes {
public class State : MySpace.State, {
    public cBRCState() : base() {
        this = new Fixture<MySpace.State>().Create(); //can't do this
    }
}
```

Now, obviously, you can't assign `this` because it is read-only. I thought of implementing either the `IFixture` or `ISpecimenBuilder` interfaces and changing the constructor to something like

```
public State () : base() {
    this.Create<MySpace.State>();
}
...
public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context) {
    return new Fixture().Create<MySpace.State>(); //can't do this either, recursive 
}
```

But I'm not grokking how to make this actually work. Am I even heading in the right direction here?

Edit: To clarify, this is not for testing. This is to provide a third party with fake data without giving them access to our real data or networks. The goal is to have our fake class stand in place of the real libraries so that the code is the same. So in our example, if I say `MySpace.State state = new MySpace.State()` or `fake.State state = new fake.State()`, I need the same object returned regardless of whether we're pointing at the fake library or the real one. And since Autofixture creates an object of type  and hands it back when you `fixture.Create<MySpace.State>()`, I need to have a fake `State` class that instantiates using Autofixture and acts as `MySpace.State` even though it's a fake.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish. If I understand correctly you are creating a new class for testing purposes only, inheriting this class on the class you are trying to test and want to use AutoFixture to create fake values in the base class? What is the scenario that requires this? If you are trying to write a specific test it would be helpful if you could include the test and what you want it to do so that we may better understand the problem.

Comment: If I say `fakes.State st = new fakes.State()`, I want the constructor to use autofixture to `.Create<MySpace.State>()` and populate `fakes.State` with data and properties. Autofixture returns an object of the original type with populated fields so I assume `fakes.State` will inherit from `MySpace.State`. This is not for testing. Our class library hits the db and a third company is doing design work for us. We can’t give them network access so we need to create dll’s that pretend and are used *exactly* like our real libraries, just with fake data and the data generated is a *lot*. Manual = No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the intent is to distinguish between internal and external behaviour by letting the third party use an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) API. In that case, I think your best option is to use a static factory method, like this:

```
namespace Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q47914153.Geo.Fakes
{
    public class State : MySpace.State
    {
        private State()
        {
        }

        public static State Create()
        {
            return new Fixture().Build<State>().FromFactory(() => new State()).Create();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the constructor is `private` in order to prevent client developers from creating an 'empty' object. (Not that I consider that a good pattern, but that seems to fit the description in the OP. Ultimately, it's your foot.)

By default, AutoFixture will ignore the private constructor, and its second option is to look for a static factory method... like `Create`. This will, if you simply use `Fixture.Create`, indeed create an infinite recursion. The trick to avoid that is to use the `Build` API, combined with `FromFactory`, because while AutoFixture by default consider `private` members taboo, it'll still happily call the `() => new State()` lambda expression.

This test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void DemoOfFactory()
{
    var state = Geo.Fakes.State.Create();

    Assert.IsType<Geo.Fakes.State>(state);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(string), state.TheText);
    Assert.NotEqual(default(int), state.TheNumber);
}
```

While I'm not sure I understand all the requirements in this scenario, something about the overall approach doesn't ring true to me. I always get uneasy when complex creation logic is hidden from me.

Instead of relying on random value generation and inheritance, could you use the Builder pattern? Here's an [article about Test Data Builders](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/08/15/test-data-builders-in-c), and while I suspect you don't need this for unit testing, you could ignore the first word in *<strike>Test</strike> Data Builder*...

Comment: It turns out that I misunderstood where the project was going (include properties in the fake class so that this problem goes away) and we don't need to do it this way. *However*, this was the direction I had been thinking of going. The thing I was missing was to build from factory. I'm going to mark your question as the answer because this was what I was going to end up doing. Well done, sir. Thanks.